# Creating multiple plots in Python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create a plot of (T/Tmax vs R/R0) for different values of Pa in a single plot like below. I have written this code that appends values to a list but all values of (T/Tmax vs R/R0) are appended in single list which does not give a good plot. What can I do to have such a plot? Also how can I make an excel sheet from the data from the loop where column 1 is T/Tmax list and column 2,3,4...are corresponding R/R0 values for different pa?

[image: Example plot]

```py
KLMDAT1 = []

KLMDAT2 = []

for j in range(z):

    pa[j] = 120000-10000*j

    i = 0
    R = R0
    q = 0
    T = 0

    while (T<Tmax):

        k1 = KLM_RKM(i*dT,R,q,pa[j])
        k2 = KLM_RKM((i+0.5)*dT,R,q+0.5*dT*k1,pa[j])
        k3 = KLM_RKM((i+0.5)*dT,R,q+0.5*dT*k2,pa[j])
        k4 = KLM_RKM((i+1)*dT,R,q+dT*k3,pa[j])

        q = q +1/6.0*dT*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
        R = R+dT*q

        if(R>0):

            KLMDAT1.append(T / Tmax)
            KLMDAT2.append(R / R0)

        if(R>Rmax):
                Rmax = R

        if (abs(q)>c or R < 0):
                    break
        T=T+dT
        i = i+1

wb.save('KLM.xlsx')

np.savetxt('KLM.csv',[KLMDAT1, KLMDAT2])

plt.plot(KLMDAT1, KLMDAT2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting it wrong. Your first variable needs to be T/Tmax. So initialize an empty T list, append T values to it, divide it by Tmax, and then plot twice: first `KLMDAT1` and then `KLMDAT2`. Following pseudocode explains it

```
KLMDAT1 = []
KLMDAT2 = []
T_list = [] # <--- Initialize T list here

for j in range(z):
    ...

    while (T<Tmax):
        ...

        T=T+dT
        T_list.append(T) # <--- Append T here
        i = i+1

# ... rest of the code

plt.plot(np.array(T_list)/Tmax, KLMDAT1) # <--- Changed here
plt.plot(np.array(T_list)/Tmax, KLMDAT2) # <--- Changed here

plt.show()
```